# How to do Try Except when a user tries to remove a value that is not in a list

Tags: python, list, input, try-except

If I have a list foods = ["a", "b"] and I let the user input the value they want to remove it gets removed from the list.

However, what I want to implement is a Try Except where if the user enters a value not in the list (let's say "c") the except prints our "value not in list".

However, when I try this, it just gives me an error. How do I fix this?

```
#lets the user takes out any food in the fridge
while True:
    try:
        foodaddition = str(input("Enter foods you want to take out of the fridge (or press Q if you had enough :)) (please note that there must be at least one item in the Fridge): "))
        if str(foodaddition).upper() == "Q" or len(foods) == 1:
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("Item not in fridge")
    foods.remove(foodaddition)
print(foods[a])
```

Comment: `input` *always* returns a `str` value; no need to call `str`, either on the return value of `input` or on `foodaddition` in the next line.

Comment: You might also want to use `while len(foods) > 1:`, as there's no point in asking for a food if you are going to break out of the loop without using it anyway.

Comment: And finally, if your loop *does* remove any items from the list, it's unlikely that `foods[a]` is relevant anymore: removing items can change the index at which the remaining items are found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use `try`/`except` you may simply move `foods.remove(foodaddition)` within the `try` branch.

However, a smarter approach would probably be to check whether the element is in the list or not, without the need of any exception handling. Find an example below:

```
# Lets the user takes out any food in the fridge
while True:
    # Ask for foods
    foodaddition = str(input("Enter foods you want to take out of the fridge (or press Q if you had enough :)) (please note that there must be at least one item in the Fridge): "))
    if str(foodaddition).upper() == "Q" or len(foods) == 1:
        break
    
    # Check if present, then remove it
    if foodaddition in foods:
        foods.remove(foodaddition)
    else:
        print("Item not in fridge")

print(foods)
```

`foodaddition in foods` returns indeed `True` when the element you are looking for is within the list, `False` otherwise.

---

By the way, it might be in your interest to check for lenght of the list *before* asking for new foods. Try the code below:

```
# Lets the user takes out any food in the fridge
while len(foods) > 1:
    # Ask for foods
    foodaddition = input("Enter foods you want to take out of the fridge (or press Q if you had enough :)) (please note that there must be at least one item in the Fridge): ")
    if foodaddition.upper() == "Q":
        break
    
    # Check if present, then remove it
    if foodaddition in foods:
        foods.remove(foodaddition)
    else:
        print("Item not in fridge")

print(foods)
```

Comment: `try..except` is more pythonic than checking before trying, really.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot. That is extremely helpful. I will play around will all 3 solutions. Thanks a lot ;).